# PHP / Javascript / HTML5 canvas - loading external images

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

Ok so I want to:

1. Grab an external image
2. Import it into a canvas object
3. Compress it
4. Save it

I have got the whole thing working with local images, however trying to import external images into a canvas object creates a security error.

By using PHP I can create a copy of the external file locally:

```
file_put_contents("copy.jpg", file_get_contents("http://external.com/image.jpg"));
```

The problem is, the external images can be quite large - up to 3MB and the canvas import tries to take place before the image has downloaded.

Is there PHP or Javascript code that waits until the file is fully downloaded?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You could just use the php script as a proxy. `imagefetch.php?src=http://example.com/kittens.jpg`. with some caching logic you'd only have to fetch the image once, and this script could be used as the canvas source - the image would only go out to the canvas once the server-side fetch has been completed.

Comment: Hi Marc, how would that work exactly? I'm quite new to this.  The image object is stored in **source_img_obj** and the canvas code is like so `var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
             cvs.width = source_img_obj.naturalWidth;
             cvs.height = source_img_obj.naturalHeight;
             var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(source_img_obj, 0, 0);
             var newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, quality/100);` Where would the imagefetch.php go?

Comment: you'd just set the canvas's image source to be your php script. and the script would basically be the equivalent of `<?php header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); readfile('http://example.com/kittens.jpg'); ?>`

Comment: Sorry I still don't follow... as part of drawImage? `var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(<?php header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); readfile('http://example.com/kittens.jpg'); ?>, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and on the sucess callback you manipulate the canvas

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait until your entire file has loaded:

`document.onload = function(){ //load image };`

If you want to wait until your canvas has loaded:

`canvas.onload = function(){ //load image };`

This is the simplest way. However, if you want more effective results, I recommend using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the external image using ajax . Manipulate the canvas inside the success callback or using a different callback function. Here's some demo code for you

```
 $.ajax({

 success: function(success) {

 process(success);

 }

});

var process = function(input){

// manipulate the canvas here

}
```